# Parse json using javascript with multiple object set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a below output from the server.And I want to get the **"result"** from the JSON input.

My JSON Input is

```
{      
"header":{  
"type":"esummary",
"version":"0.3"
},
"result":{  
    "28885854":{  
    "uid":"28885854",
    "pubdate":"2017 Sep 8",
    "epubdate":"2017 Sep 8",
    "source":"J Org Chem",
    }
  }
}
```

And I prefer only **javascript**.Anyone help me to do this.

**EDIT** :

I tried the code to get JSON from server

```
var json = JSON.stringify(temp1);
console.log(json)
```

My original output in the console was like this.

"
**{"header":{"type":"esummary","version":"0.3"},"result":{"28885854":{"uid":"28885854","pubdate":"2017 Sep 8","epubdate":"2017 Sep 8","source":"J Org Chem","authors":[{"name":"Farmer LA","authtype":"Author","clusterid":""},{"name":"Haidasz EA","authtype":"Author","clusterid":""},{"name":"Griesser M","authtype":"Author","clusterid":""},{"name":"Pratt DA","authtype":"Author","clusterid":""}],"lastauthor":"Pratt DA","title":"Phenoxazine: A Privileged Scaffold for Radical-Trapping Antioxidants.","sorttitle":"phenoxazine a privileged scaffold for radical trapping antioxidants","volume":"","issue":"","pages":"","lang":["eng"],"nlmuniqueid":"2985193R","issn":"0022-3263","essn":"1520-6904","pubtype":["Journal Article"],"recordstatus":"PubMed - as supplied by publisher","pubstatus":"10","articleids":[{"idtype":"pubmed","idtypen":1,"value":"28885854"},{"idtype":"doi","idtypen":3,"value":"10.1021/acs.joc.7b02025"},{"idtype":"rid","idtypen":8,"value":"28885854"},{"idtype":"eid","idtypen":8,"value":"28885854"}],"history":[{"pubstatus":"entrez","date":"2017/09/09 06:00"},{"pubstatus":"pubmed","date":"2017/09/09 06:00"},{"pubstatus":"medline","date":"2017/09/09 06:00"}],"references":[],"attributes":["Has Abstract"],"pmcrefcount":"","fulljournalname":"The Journal of organic chemistry","elocationid":"doi: 10.1021/acs.joc.7b02025","doctype":"citation","srccontriblist":[],"booktitle":"","medium":"","edition":"","publisherlocation":"","publishername":"","srcdate":"","reportnumber":"","availablefromurl":"","locationlabel":"","doccontriblist":[],"docdate":"","bookname":"","chapter":"","sortpubdate":"2017/09/08 00:00","sortfirstauthor":"Farmer LA","vernaculartitle":""},"uids":["28885854"]}}**
"

[image: Object What i Get]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think all you're looking for is `.result`. Perhaps you also want `JSON.parse(...)` if you have just the JSON string so far.

```js
var obj = {
  "header": {
    "type": "esummary",
    "version": "0.3"
  },
  "result": {
    "28885854": {
      "uid": "28885854",
      "pubdate": "2017 Sep 8",
      "epubdate": "2017 Sep 8",
      "source": "J Org Chem",
    }
  }
};

console.log(obj.result);

// To address edits above and comments below:
console.log(obj.result["28885854"].source);
```

Comment: When i'm using **console.log(json.result)** it will give undefined

Comment: Why are you calling `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: Per your edit, don't you just want `console.log(temp1.result)`?

Comment: temp1 is not a JSON

Comment: So,that I'm using the way I said

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say. If `console.log(temp1.result)` doesn't work, then perhaps `temp1` is a JSON string, in which case try `console.log(JSON.parse(temp1).result)`.

Comment: see the above image.I tried to get Object using obj.28885854.authors.Then it will give an Error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number**

Comment: `obj["28885854"].authors`

Comment: What can I do now ?? That's Why I'm going to convert this Object into JSON then getting trouble from that

Comment: Oops!!! That Works great.Thank you very much.Post this Result also.So,somebody have an idea with it.